# differentiate between different enter event in vue js

Tags: vuejs2

With vue js i have developed a chat app. when typing message there might have some suggestion from keyboard. to select that suggested text when i press enter button it sends that suggested message. but sending is not my requirement. i want to select the suggestion. after finishing my message i want to send the message by enter button.
here is my code:

```
<textarea v-model="Keijiban" @keyup.enter="send" @click="selectContact(kokyaku1)" placeholder="ここにメッセージを入力してください。"></textarea>
```

in chrome it is working well. But this problem is appearing when i am using inter explorer(IE).

Comment: Which version of the IE did you test with?

Comment: Vue does not support IE8 and below, because it uses ECMAScript 5 features that are unshimmable in IE8. However it supports all ECMAScript 5 compliant browsers.